# Game Loop Event Listening

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

I have this loop for motion in a snake like game

Motion

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        #Arrow keys move snake head.
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_y_change=0
                lead_x_change -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_y_change=0
                lead_x_change += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_x_change=0
                lead_y_change -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_x_change=0
                lead_y_change += 10

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change
    
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x, lead_y, 10, 10])
        pygame.display.update()
```

What should happen:

When I press any of the arrow keys the loop should run over and over updating the motion and the little black rectangle should fly of the screen never to be seen again.

What happens:

The rectangle moves 10 upon key down and then 10 upon key up. Then 20 on key down and 20 on key up and so on . . . It also seems to react to mouse motion. I have no idea why. I am using python 3.4 and pygame 1.9.

What is going on? How do I correct it to get the expected result?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about reducing the indent of the lines starting with `lead_x += lead_x_change`?  Right now it will only go to those lines when an event occurs.

Comment: Could you provide a runnable [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain exactly what you want the program to do? Do you want the box to move in a straight line at a constant rate after a single keypress? Or something else?

Comment: Ohhhh, I see the indentation problem now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Posting as an answer so this question can be finished properly]*

It looks like the lines starting with `lead_x += lead_x_change` need to be outdented one level.  Right now it will only go to those lines when an event occurs.